# Converting TimeUnit to ChronoUnit?

Tags: java, java-time

Java 8 introduced [ChronoUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) which is largely equivalent to [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) introduced in Java 5.

Is there an existing function for converting a TimeUnit to ChronoUnit? (Yes, I know how to write my own)

Comment: You should note that not every `ChronoUnit` is mappable to `TimeUnit`, for example `MONTHS`. What will you do in this case?

Comment: @MenoHochschild, good point. I was actually only interested in one-way mapping. I will update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

## Java 9

In Java 9 the `TimeUnit` API got extended and allows to convert between `TimeUnit` and `ChronoUnit`:

```
TimeUnit.toChronoUnit() // returns a ChronoUnit
TimeUnit.of(ChronoUnit chronoUnit) // returns a TimeUnit
```

see: [JDK-8141452](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8141452)

Answer (score 14):

At one stage during the development, you could could construct a `Duration` from a `TimeUnit`.
https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten/blob/3b4c40e3e7a5dd7a4993ee19e1c156e4e65432b3/src/main/java/javax/time/Duration.java#L293 However this was removed for the final version of the code in Java SE 8.

I don't know of any pre-packaged routine to do the conversion, but it should be added to [ThreeTen-Extra](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra), probably in `Temporals`.

**UPDATE**: This was fixed by https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra/issues/22

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Are there plans to add this into the core API in the future?

Comment: I don't have any immediate plans for this, but i t would make sense to do so.

Comment: @Gili — Note that it was added to the core API in Java 9: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35744437/1108305

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8

For those of us using Java 8, you can copy `toChronoUnit` from the [TimeUnit source code](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk12u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.java#L456) in a later JDK and make it into a static method to achieve the same end:

```
public static ChronoUnit toChronoUnit(TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    switch (timeUnit) {
        case NANOSECONDS:
            return ChronoUnit.NANOS;
        case MICROSECONDS:
            return ChronoUnit.MICROS;
        case MILLISECONDS:
            return ChronoUnit.MILLIS;
        case SECONDS:
            return ChronoUnit.SECONDS;
        case MINUTES:
            return ChronoUnit.MINUTES;
        case HOURS:
            return ChronoUnit.HOURS;
        case DAYS:
            return ChronoUnit.DAYS;
        default:
            throw new AssertionError();
    }
}
```